# How to customize input field length in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have 4 input fields and type of each field is *number*. I have implemented it as follows

```
<div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
            <div class="column mr-3">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Available Amount : <br/><input type="number"
                                                   class="mr-3"
                                                   [(ngModel)]="selectedItemAvailability"
                                                   [disabled]="true">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="column ml-5">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Enter Quantity : <br/><input type="number"
                                                 [min]="1"
                                                 [max]="selectedItemAvailability"
                                                 [(ngModel)]="selectedItemQuantity">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
            <div class="column mr-3">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Price : <br/><input type="number"
                                        [min]="0"
                                        class="mr-3"
                                        [(ngModel)]="selectedItemPrice">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="column ml-5">
                <label class="col-form-label">
                    Item Discount : <br/><input type="number"
                                                [min]="0"
                                                [max]="100"
                                                class="mr-3"
                                                [(ngModel)]="selectedItemDiscount">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Once the program is executed, it gives me the interface as below,

[image]

When I use input type as *text*, it gives the expected output.
I want to make all the input fields same in length while using the input type as *number*. How can I achieve this?

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the stackblitz i have provided?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code works perfect. Please check stackblitz for the detail:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b7xnya?file=src/app/app.component.html

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
  <div class="column mr-3">
    <label class="col-form-label">
      Available Amount : <br /><input type="number" class="mr-3">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="column ml-5">
    <label class="col-form-label">
      Enter Quantity : <br /><input type="number">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
  <div class="column mr-3">
    <label class="col-form-label">
      Price : <br /><input type="number" [min]="0" class="mr-3">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="column ml-5">
    <label class="col-form-label">
      Item Discount : <br /><input type="number" class="mr-3">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I need to bind data too. How can I do that?

Comment: Binding data should not cause any issue with styling. Check if there are any CSS may conflict with bootstrap4 in your project.

Comment: @ManujayaPremathilaka The stackblitz with data binding integrated. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b7xnya?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I just removed the ```[max]``` property from the ```input``` field and then the problem solved. But I want to use the ```max``` property too!

Comment: Adding [max] will not cause issue, can you reproduce the issue in the stackblitz? You can directly modify it on my stackbliz